# Change ListView choiceMode from singleChoice to multipleChoiceModal on button click when using ArrayAdapters

Tags: java, android

Actually, I want to achieve something like the functionality we mostly see in our cell phones for chats/msgs deletion. When a delete button is clicked on the menu, checkboxes must appear for row selection along with the label on top displaying the no. of selected rows. When "Done/Delete" button on the top right side is clicked after selecting the no. of rows, a delete confirmation dialog box must appear and selected rows must be deleted. I have highlighted the required functionality in images below. [image 1-button in menu ][1][Image 2- multi-mode appearance on clicking the delete button][2][image 3- selection and label][3][image 4- confirmation dialog box][4].This is what I coded so far but my code ain't working, need help. here's my code:

```
//for the start I want the list be in single mode

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter arrList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, namesList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrList);

 // for the list to be in multimode on clicking the button in the menu

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return true;
        }  
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.deletebutton) {
        if (namesList.size() != 0) {
                if (mListView.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) {
                    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
                    namesList);
                    delete();
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "names not found", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
// delete method implementation
        AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                a_builder.setTitle("Confirm Delete?");
                a_builder.setMessage("DELETE")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                int i;
                                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                                int itemCount = listView.getCount();
                                for (i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                    if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                                        arrList.remove(namesList.get(i));
                                    }
                                }
                                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                                arrList.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR1Wv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gJGd.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvn9p.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gsML.png
```

Comment: You can do that by creating check boxes for each element in listbox and hide them till user wants to select more than one element and then display them

Comment: Can u please point out where i'm doing wrong in my code ?? Why ain't it working?

Comment: I even tried the answers given on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251095/change-listview-choicemode-from-singlechoice-to-multiplechoicemodal but no luck so far. Need help!