# Multi select from the List

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a List where I need to select multiple options from the list. In the list if the user had already availed the leaves those will get shaded or user cannot select.[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMTww.jpg)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251095/change-listview-choicemode-from-singlechoice-to-multiplechoicemodal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251095/change-listview-choicemode-from-singlechoice-to-multiplechoicemodal)

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection